# Make rows non editable after printing

Tags: google-apps-script

My users click a menu option to print a row. The value in Column X is set to 1 while printing.

I use the below code (runs once an hour from the owner's account) to make sure that the row becomes "Read only" after printing.

The below function has two problems.

1.The user can edit till the below function runs
2.The function fails to run most of the time, throwing error "exceeded maximum time"

I have made "data validation" for important columns with formula =$X920:$X=0

But, this validation has two problems

1.user can delete the value in the cell
2.user can copy-paste from another cell to bye-pass the validation

I need a suggestion how to make a row read only if the value in X==1

```
function lock_row(){ 
  //prevent deletion / edit after printing 
  // timer to run every hour in owner account
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var gpsht = ss.getSheetByName("GatePass");  
  var gplr=gpsht.getLastRow();
  var locks = gpsht.getRange("W:X").getValues();
  for (j=gplr-2 ; j > 1 ;j--){
    if (locks[j][0]=="" && locks[j][1]==1 ) { //not yet locked , printed
      //to prevent others from editing printed rows
      var protection = ss.getRange('A'+(j+1)+':Q'+(j+1)).protect();
      protection.setDescription('Locked')
      .removeEditors(['xx@gmail.com', 'yy@ar.com', 'syy@min.co.in', 'co@mar.com', 'ts@mn.co.in']);
      gpsht.getRange("W"+(j+1)).setValue(1);
     }//if
  }//for 
}//function
//
```

### Additional infos:

I'm giving the function (which has to be invoked from a custom menu I built) which does the printing (it fills another sheet from the values picked from the rows).   I am thinking of invoking the function from "On edit" trigger (which will be run from owner account). I will include a column (drop down) and when the user changes the value to "Print", the function (on edit) will run (from owner account) and it will remove all editors (other than the owner). I think I can make the idea work) Thanks for the suggestion.

```
function print_gp_3() {
  //to make gate pass using array 16-3-20
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var activesheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (activesheet!=="GatePass") {Browser.msgBox('Pl. click this option from "GatePass" sheet');return;};    
  var gpsht = ss.getSheetByName("GatePass");  
  var gprow = gpsht.getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();     
  var gph = gpsht.getRange("A"+gprow+":AA"+gprow).getValues();
  if (gph[0][0].indexOf(gph[0][1]) > -1 ) {} else {Browser.msgBox('Gate Pass number and From Dept not matching');return;};
  if (gph[0][1]==gph[0][3]) {Browser.msgBox('You can NOT send material to yourself');return;};
  if (gph[0][0].indexOf(gph[0][1]) > -1 ) {} else {Browser.msgBox('Gate Pass number and From Dept not matching');return;};
  if ( gph[0][10] &&  gph[0][24]=="") { //returnable GP and Request by not fed
     var reqby =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Requested By (Name)").getResponseText();
     if (reqby=="") {Browser.msgBox('Pl. feed the name of the person requesting the Gate Pass');return;};
     gpsht.getRange("Y"+gprow).setValue(reqby);
    };
  var currentemail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var setupsht = ss.getSheetByName("Setup");  
  var emails=setupsht.getRange("H2:J17").getValues();
  var deptemails=setupsht.getRange("N2:O35").getValues();
  var depem="";
  var unit="", seq="", m=1, today=new Date(), invdt="";
  var uemails=ArrayLib.filterByText(emails, 0, currentemail)
  var unit=uemails[0][1];
  var seq=uemails[0][2];
  if (seq == gph[0][1]) {} else {Browser.msgBox("You are not authorised to print other unit Gate Pass"); return; };
  var gpnos=gpsht.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var gpvals=[];  //ArrayLib.filterByText(allgpvals, 0 , gph[0][0]);
  var printsht=ss.getSheetByName(seq);
  var nr=true, ret=false;//normal
  if (gph[0][10]==true) {nr=false; ret=true} ;//RETURNABLE
  if (gph[0][16]==""){invdt=""} else {invdt=Utilities.formatDate( gph[0][16] ,"GMT+05:30", "dd-MM-yy")};
  var inv=gph[0][15] +" "+invdt  ; //invno/DCno+dt
  var prin=[["Megawin","","","","","SENDER COPY","","","","","Megawin","","","","","RECEIVER COPY",""],
            ["MATERIAL GATE PASS","","","","","No",gph[0][0],"","","","MATERIAL GATE PASS","","","","","No",gph[0][0]],
            ["From",gph[0][1],"","","","Date",gph[0][5],"","","","From",gph[0][1],"","","","Date",gph[0][5]],
            ["Dept.",gph[0][2],"",ret,"Returnable",nr,"Non-Returnable","","","","Dept",gph[0][2],"",ret,"Returnable",nr,"Non-Returnable"],
            ["To",gph[0][3],"","","","Despatch Through",gph[0][9],"","","","To",gph[0][3],"","","","Despatch Through",gph[0][9]],
            ["Dept.",gph[0][4],"","","By Person",gph[0][12],"","","","","Dept.",gph[0][4],"","","By Person",gph[0][12],""],
            ["S.No.","Description of the items","","","","Uom","Qty","","","","S.No.","Description of the items","","","","Uom","Qty"],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["Purpose",gph[0][3],"","","","","","","","","Purpose",gph[0][3],"","","","",""],
            ["PO No.:",gph[0][13],"","","Doc No./Date:",inv,"","","","","PO No.:",gph[0][13],"","","Doc No./Date:",inv,""],
            ["Taken out By Name & Sign","","","","","","","","","","Taken out By Name & Sign","","","","","",""],
            ["Stores In-Charge : Name and Sign","","","","","","","","","","Stores In-Charge : Name and Sign","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","Entry Gate Seal/Date/Time/Slno.","","","","","Exit Gate Seal/Date/Time/Slno.",""]];
  var chkgp=gph[0][3] +gph[0][1] +  gph[0][10] ; 
  var m=1;
  for (j=0;j<gpnos.length;j++){ //all gp no
    if (gpnos[j][0]==gph[0][0]){//filtered for selected gp no
      gpvals=gpsht.getRange("A"+(j+1)+":X"+(j+1)).getValues();
      if (j==10) {Browser.msgBox("Only 10 items allowed in a Pass. Pl. delete lines and make new Gate Pass");break};
      if (chkgp===gpvals[0][3] + gpvals[0][1] +  gpvals[0][10]) {} else { Browser.msgBox("Pl. check from / to / returnable. Do not mix"); return;}  ;   
      prin[6+m][0]=m;
      prin[6+m][1]=gpvals[0][6];
      prin[6+m][5]=gpvals[0][7];
      prin[6+m][6]=gpvals[0][8];
      prin[6+m][10]=m;
      prin[6+m][11]=gpvals[0][6];
      prin[6+m][15]=gpvals[0][7];
      prin[6+m][16]=gpvals[0][8];
      //set x-printed=1
      if (gpvals[0][23]=="") {gpsht.getRange("X"+(j+1)).setValue(1)};
      //to make dept email list
      for (n=0;n<33;n++){
        if (gpvals[0][4]==deptemails[n][0]){
          if (depem.indexOf(deptemails[n][1])>-1) {} else {
            depem+=deptemails[n][1]+",";
          }//if
        }//if
      }//for
      m++;
    }//if gp no match
  }//for number of items in gp
  printsht.getRange("A1:Q22").setDataValidation(null);
  printsht.getRange(1,1,22,17).setValues(prin);
  // block editing after printing
  var cell = printsht.getRange( "A1:Q22");
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireTextEqualTo('$$').setAllowInvalid(false).setHelpText("Do not edit in print sheet").build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
  //to get tick mark for returnable
  printsht.getRange("D4").setDataValidation(null);
  printsht.getRange("F4").setDataValidation(null);  
  printsht.getRange('D4').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).requireCheckbox().build()); 
  printsht.getRange('F4').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).requireCheckbox().build()); 
  printsht.getRange("N4").setDataValidation(null);
  printsht.getRange("P4").setDataValidation(null);  
  printsht.getRange('N4').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).requireCheckbox().build()); 
  printsht.getRange('P4').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).requireCheckbox().build()); 
  printsht.activate();
  //send auto email to receipien stores and receipient dept - 17-3-20
  if (gph[0][26]=="" && gpvals[0][23]=="" ){} else { //chk email id if to = any megawin unit and if not already printed
  // array formula              x=1 printed
    var TABLEFORMAT ="<table cellspacing='2' cellpadding='2' dir='ltr' border='1' style='font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal'"
    var htmltable = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT +' ">';
    prin[2][6]=Utilities.formatDate( prin[2][6] ,"GMT+05:30", "dd-MM-yy");
    prin[1][0]="";
    for (row = 0; row<19; row++){
      htmltable += '<tr>';
      for (col = 0 ;col<7; col++){
        if (prin[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + '' + '</td>';} 
          else
          if (row === 0)  {
            htmltable += '<th>' + prin[row][col] + '</th>';
            }
          else {htmltable += '<td>' + prin[row][col] + '</td>';}
          }
      htmltable += '</tr>';
    }//for
    htmltable += '</table>';
    //MailApp.sendEmail(gph[0][26], 'Gate Pass '+gph[0][0] ,'' ,{htmlBody: htmltable})
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to:gph[0][26],
      cc:depem,
      subject: 'Gate Pass '+gph[0][0],
      htmlBody: htmltable})
  }//if email id found and not already printed
  printsht.activate();
}//function
//
//
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### NEW ANSWER

You can use an installable trigger to run a function with the owner authority. Trigger this function with an onEdit event based on a dropdown list. In my example the dropdown values triggering the protection function is "Print".
When the user finishes to work on the selected row, just by changing the value in the dropdown the onEdit trigger will run.

You as an owner have to install the trigger first.

```
function installOnEditTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEditCustom') //name of the function the trigger will run
  .forSpreadsheet(spreadsheetID)
  .onEdit()
  .create();
}
```

Now you can use your custom event handler to perform the range protection.

```
function onEditCustom(e) {
  //Make sure the edit targets our protected column
  if (e.range.getColumn() === 24){
    if (e.value == 'Print') {
      let row = e.range.getRow();
      var protection = e.source.getRange('A'+(row)+':Q'+(row)).protect();
      protection.setDescription('Locked')
       .removeEditors(editorsBlackList); //Just a placeholder for your ['xx@gmail.com', ... ]
    }
  };
}
```

===

### OLD ANSWER

#### Approach:

First I would proceed to protect the "data validation" row.

In my example I would remove any existing editor and add only the user who runs the script as an editor. This way nobody can edit the validation row but you.

Snippet 1:

```
function protectValidationRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var protection = ss.getSheetByName("GatePass").getRange("X1:X").protect();
  //Ensure that only the owner of the script can edit the column
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  protection.addEditor(me);
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

Then instead of running a function each hour to lock the row if X==1 I would use an onEdit trigger that locks the correspondent row once the X value is set to 1.

Snippet 2:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //Make sure the edit targets our protected column
  if (e.range.getColumn() === 24){
    if (e.value == 1) {
      let row = e.range.getRow();
      var protection = e.source.getRange('A'+(row)+':Q'+(row)).protect();
      protection.setDescription('Locked')
      .removeEditors(editorsBlackList); //Just a placeholder for your ['xx@gmail.com', ... ]
    }
  };
}
```

#### References:

[Protection Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)

[onEdit Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

### Edit:

Assuming you are the owner once you execute the protectValidationRow function nobody else can execute it again. Any editor who tries to run that function will get permission errors.

Plus, since you don't want the editors to run nor edit your scripts you should create a standalone project. This won't be bound to your spreadsheet and you can create it in Google Drive: click NEW > MORE > Google Apps Script.

Keep in mind you will have to replace every `.getActiveSpreadsheet()` with `.openFileById(SpreadsheetId)`.
Note that you can retrieve your `spreadsheetID` from the url:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetID/edit#gid=0
```

You are right, `onEdit(e)` triggers don't run if the value is NOT set manually.
As a workaround I suggest to execute the lock function whenever you use the `.setValue()` function in your script.
So if you have a function that eventually will set the value of a cell in the column X to 1 you can do the following:

```
function yourFunction() {

  /*

  ...

  */

  gpsht.getRange('X'+(row)).setValue(1);

  //Protect the range after setting the value
  var protection = e.source.getRange('A'+(row)+':Q'+(row)).protect();
  protection.setDescription('Locked').removeEditors(editorsBlackList); //Just a placeholder for your ['xx@gmail.com', ... ]
}

### References:

[Protection Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)

[Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
```

Comment: I want the user (who has edit rights) should not edit it after it is printed.

Comment: The above code you provided makes it "read only" for all other uses  (other than the current user who is an editor). But, I want that the current user (editor) must not be able to edit it. Only the owner must be able to edit

Comment: The X=1 is not set manually. It is set by a script. onEdit() will not work if the cell value is set by setValue() method (if I'm right - need to check it). But, the idea is good. Need to develop it further

Comment: Still the core issue is not solved. The user (editor) will run the function all right. But, he can not remove himself as an editor. Only the owner can remove all other editors. That's why I am running the lock function once an hour (as owner).

Comment: I'll need some additional information about the user tasks. What exactly does the button the user clicks? Since the core issue depends on this, please share with me the code of the function the button runs when clicked. Thanks.

Comment: Mars  --- I still have some doubts - The InstalloneditTrigger will be installed "On edit". It will try to run (and install the trigger) each time a user edits a field. It will run multiple times continuously. Will it not slow down the system?  What is the need for installing the trigger multiple times? What is the need for this function when we can achieve the desired result by running the "oneditcustom" trigger  set by the owner "onEdit" of any field.

Comment: No the install trigger function must be run only once. You should run it from the Apps Script Project.

Comment: makes sense. let me try

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving the function (which has to be invoked from a custom menu I built) which does the printing (it fills another sheet from the values picked from the rows).   I am thinking of invoking the function from "On edit" trigger (which will be run from owner account). I will include a column (drop down) and when the user changes the value to "Print", the function (on edit) will run (from owner account) and it will remove all editors (other than the owner). I think I can make the idea work) Thanks for the suggestion.

```
function print_gp_3() {
  //to make gate pass using array 16-3-20
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var activesheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (activesheet!=="GatePass") {Browser.msgBox('Pl. click this option from "GatePass" sheet');return;};    
  var gpsht = ss.getSheetByName("GatePass");  
  var gprow = gpsht.getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();     
  var gph = gpsht.getRange("A"+gprow+":AA"+gprow).getValues();
  if (gph[0][0].indexOf(gph[0][1]) > -1 ) {} else {Browser.msgBox('Gate Pass number and From Dept not matching');return;};
  if (gph[0][1]==gph[0][3]) {Browser.msgBox('You can NOT send material to yourself');return;};
  if (gph[0][0].indexOf(gph[0][1]) > -1 ) {} else {Browser.msgBox('Gate Pass number and From Dept not matching');return;};
  if ( gph[0][10] &&  gph[0][24]=="") { //returnable GP and Request by not fed
     var reqby =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Requested By (Name)").getResponseText();
     if (reqby=="") {Browser.msgBox('Pl. feed the name of the person requesting the Gate Pass');return;};
     gpsht.getRange("Y"+gprow).setValue(reqby);
    };
  var currentemail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var setupsht = ss.getSheetByName("Setup");  
  var emails=setupsht.getRange("H2:J17").getValues();
  var deptemails=setupsht.getRange("N2:O35").getValues();
  var depem="";
  var unit="", seq="", m=1, today=new Date(), invdt="";
  var uemails=ArrayLib.filterByText(emails, 0, currentemail)
  var unit=uemails[0][1];
  var seq=uemails[0][2];
  if (seq == gph[0][1]) {} else {Browser.msgBox("You are not authorised to print other unit Gate Pass"); return; };
  var gpnos=gpsht.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var gpvals=[];  //ArrayLib.filterByText(allgpvals, 0 , gph[0][0]);
  var printsht=ss.getSheetByName(seq);
  var nr=true, ret=false;//normal
  if (gph[0][10]==true) {nr=false; ret=true} ;//RETURNABLE
  if (gph[0][16]==""){invdt=""} else {invdt=Utilities.formatDate( gph[0][16] ,"GMT+05:30", "dd-MM-yy")};
  var inv=gph[0][15] +" "+invdt  ; //invno/DCno+dt
  var prin=[["Megawin","","","","","SENDER COPY","","","","","Megawin","","","","","RECEIVER COPY",""],
            ["MATERIAL GATE PASS","","","","","No",gph[0][0],"","","","MATERIAL GATE PASS","","","","","No",gph[0][0]],
            ["From",gph[0][1],"","","","Date",gph[0][5],"","","","From",gph[0][1],"","","","Date",gph[0][5]],
            ["Dept.",gph[0][2],"",ret,"Returnable",nr,"Non-Returnable","","","","Dept",gph[0][2],"",ret,"Returnable",nr,"Non-Returnable"],
            ["To",gph[0][3],"","","","Despatch Through",gph[0][9],"","","","To",gph[0][3],"","","","Despatch Through",gph[0][9]],
            ["Dept.",gph[0][4],"","","By Person",gph[0][12],"","","","","Dept.",gph[0][4],"","","By Person",gph[0][12],""],
            ["S.No.","Description of the items","","","","Uom","Qty","","","","S.No.","Description of the items","","","","Uom","Qty"],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],
            ["Purpose",gph[0][3],"","","","","","","","","Purpose",gph[0][3],"","","","",""],
            ["PO No.:",gph[0][13],"","","Doc No./Date:",inv,"","","","","PO No.:",gph[0][13],"","","Doc No./Date:",inv,""],
            ["Taken out By Name & Sign","","","","","","","","","","Taken out By Name & Sign","","","","","",""],
            ["Stores In-Charge : Name and Sign","","","","","","","","","","Stores In-Charge : Name and Sign","","","","","",""],
            ["","","","","","","","","","","Entry Gate Seal/Date/Time/Slno.","","","","","Exit Gate Seal/Date/Time/Slno.",""]];
  var chkgp=gph[0][3] +gph[0][1] +  gph[0][10] ; 
  var m=1;
  for (j=0;j<gpnos.length;j++){ //all gp no
    if (gpnos[j][0]==gph[0][0]){//filtered for selected gp no
      gpvals=gpsht.getRange("A"+(j+1)+":X"+(j+1)).getValues();
      if (j==10) {Browser.msgBox("Only 10 items allowed in a Pass. Pl. delete lines and make new Gate Pass");break};
      if (chkgp===gpvals[0][3] + gpvals[0][1] +  gpvals[0][10]) {} else { Browser.msgBox("Pl. check from / to / returnable. Do not mix"); return;}  ;   
      prin[6+m][0]=m;
      prin[6+m][1]=gpvals[0][6];
      prin[6+m][5]=gpvals[0][7];
      prin[6+m][6]=gpvals[0][8];
      prin[6+m][10]=m;
      prin[6+m][11]=gpvals[0][6];
      prin[6+m][15]=gpvals[0][7];
      prin[6+m][16]=gpvals[0][8];
      //set x-printed=1
      if (gpvals[0][23]=="") {gpsht.getRange("X"+(j+1)).setValue(1)};
      //to make dept email list
      for (n=0;n<33;n++){
        if (gpvals[0][4]==deptemails[n][0]){
          if (depem.indexOf(deptemails[n][1])>-1) {} else {
            depem+=deptemails[n][1]+",";
          }//if
        }//if
      }//for
      m++;
    }//if gp no match
  }//for number of items in gp
  printsht.getRange("A1:Q22").setDataValidation(null);
  printsht.getRange(1,1,22,17).setValues(prin);
  // block editing after printing
  var cell = printsht.getRange( "A1:Q22");
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireTextEqualTo('$$').setAllowInvalid(false).setHelpText("Do not edit in print sheet").build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
  //to get tick mark for returnable
  printsht.getRange("D4").setDataValidation(null);
  printsht.getRange("F4").setDataValidation(null);  
  printsht.getRange('D4').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).requireCheckbox().build()); 
  printsht.getRange('F4').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).requireCheckbox().build()); 
  printsht.getRange("N4").setDataValidation(null);
  printsht.getRange("P4").setDataValidation(null);  
  printsht.getRange('N4').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).requireCheckbox().build()); 
  printsht.getRange('P4').setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().setAllowInvalid(false).requireCheckbox().build()); 
  printsht.activate();
  //send auto email to receipien stores and receipient dept - 17-3-20
  if (gph[0][26]=="" && gpvals[0][23]=="" ){} else { //chk email id if to = any megawin unit and if not already printed
  // array formula              x=1 printed
    var TABLEFORMAT ="<table cellspacing='2' cellpadding='2' dir='ltr' border='1' style='font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal'"
    var htmltable = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT +' ">';
    prin[2][6]=Utilities.formatDate( prin[2][6] ,"GMT+05:30", "dd-MM-yy");
    prin[1][0]="";
    for (row = 0; row<19; row++){
      htmltable += '<tr>';
      for (col = 0 ;col<7; col++){
        if (prin[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + '' + '</td>';} 
          else
          if (row === 0)  {
            htmltable += '<th>' + prin[row][col] + '</th>';
            }
          else {htmltable += '<td>' + prin[row][col] + '</td>';}
          }
      htmltable += '</tr>';
    }//for
    htmltable += '</table>';
    //MailApp.sendEmail(gph[0][26], 'Gate Pass '+gph[0][0] ,'' ,{htmlBody: htmltable})
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to:gph[0][26],
      cc:depem,
      subject: 'Gate Pass '+gph[0][0],
      htmlBody: htmltable})
  }//if email id found and not already printed
  printsht.activate();
}//function
//
//
```